# Read Specific Lines from a text file and then outputing java

Tags: java, arrays

I have a text file that has a list of values formatted like so:

```
FirstName LastName
Labs
10, 25, 25, 15, 30, 50, 40, 40, 40, 25, 50
10, 25, 25, 15, 29, 49, 39, 39, 39, 25, 49
Homework
100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100
100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 93
Quizzes
10, 10, 15, 10, 9, 10, 15
8, 10, 11, 9, 7, 7, 11
Exams
100, 100, 100, 100, 100
96, 78, 88, 62, 92
```

Is there a way I can take a specific line, say the line under exams where it reads all 100, and store just that line into a 1D array?

Comment: You have more than one row under "Exams." Why would you read the first line and not the next one?

Comment: You would read the first line into one variable, then the second line into another, then find the average.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to read through the file until you reach the point where you can read exams out of the file, and then prepare to insert the values into your array.
So you need to read the file, start searching for your exam keyword, and then on the next line start reading values until you reach however many you want, or end of file/line.

Answer (score 0):

Two ways:

1. You can use Java's `RandomAccessFile` class.
2. You can use a regular expression to find the part you need.

I will edit this answer later to provide examples of both (if someone else doesn't do it sooner)

**UPDATE**: Using RandomAccessFile (this was done in hurry. There might be a better way)

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    RandomAccessFile file = null;
    try
    {
        file = new RandomAccessFile("grades.txt", "r"); // read-only file
        while(!file.readLine().startsWith("Exams"))
        {
            file.seek(file.getFilePointer());
        }
        // Get the numbers and add them
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
         e.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally
    {
        try
        {
            file.close();
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

The `while()` loop is moving the pointer to the next line following "Exams."  You can keep track of how many bytes remained to be read, and create an array of bytes that reads the file from the current position.  I will not read until the end, because "Exams" might not be the last record.  To make it work with all parts of the file (i.e. Homework) you have to be a bit more clever so that you don't end up getting more data than you need.  But that is the idea behind `RandomAccessFile`.  This class also works great when you have to input a new grade under "Exams."  For that case, the file permissions will have to be set to "rw".

If you can guarantee the structure of the file will never change, `RandomAccessFile` is great because you can quickly go to different parts of the file, read and/or write information to it, and move on.  You can think of it as a very low-level database.